# Verifying my proof of the intersection of $\sigma$-algebras is also a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

It has been a while since I've done proofs so I would like to verify if my proof is correct. I feel like I cheated or skipped a step but I am not sure how. Here is what I have to prove:

**Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be two $\sigma -$Algebras over a set $\Omega$. Show that $F_1 \cap F_2$ is also a $\sigma -$Algebra over a set $\Omega$**

Claim:

$F_1 \subset F_2$ or  $F_2 \subset F_1$ or $F_1 \cap F_2 = \{\emptyset, \Omega \}$

Clearly if $F_1 \cap F_2 = \{\emptyset, \Omega \}$ then it is a $\sigma -$Algebra over a set $\Omega$

Now, for the nontrivial case, WLOG, I claim $F_1 \subset F_2$

Assume by contradiction this is not the case.

Let $A \subset F_1$ non-empty such that $A \cap F_2 = \emptyset$ so that $F_1 \backslash A \subset F_2$  $\quad$ ($F_1$ minus $A$)

$\therefore \quad (F_1 \backslash A)^c \subset F_2$ as $F_2$ is closed under set complements

$\therefore \quad (F_1 \cap A^c)^c \subset F_2$

$\therefore \quad (F_1^c \cup A) \subset F_2$

$\therefore \quad A \subset F_2$ CONTRADICTION

$\therefore \quad F_1 \subset F_2$

$\therefore \quad F_1 \cap F_2 = F_1$ which is $\sigma -$Algebra over a set $\Omega$

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: $F_1 \subset F_2$ would lead to $F_1\cap F_2=F_1$ which is already a $\sigma$-algebra. This is one case of many cases. Try to prove the axioms one by one. It will get you your result.

Comment: I think none of the answers/comments address this clearly, so I will: your claim is completely false. There is absolutely no reason that $F_1\subset F_2$, $F_2\subset F_1$ or $F_1\cap F_2 = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$. There are infinitely many other possibilities.

Comment: Can you give me two sigma algebras such that their intersection is non trivial and are not subsets of each other? I'm having a hard time finding an example!
Assuming there are some, perhaps if we tightened the definition to borel sigmal algebra, would my proof work then? Otherwise Is there a special condition under which my proof works? @CaptainLama

Comment: There is no reasonable way to salvage your claim, it is really fundamentally false. A stupid example would be to take three elements $a,b,c\in \Omega$ and consider $F_1$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra of sets containing either both $a$ and $b$ or none of the two, and likewise for $F_2$ with $a$ and $c$. Then $F_1\cap F_2$ is the algebra of subsets containing either $a$, $b$ and $c$, or none of them.

Comment: @CaptainLama Note that your example fails if $\Omega = \{a,b,c\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in concluding that $(F_1 \backslash A)^c \subset F_2$. The fact that $F_2$ is closed under complements means that $B \in F_2$ implies $B^c \in F_2$, not that $B \subset F_2$ implies $B^c \subset F_2$.

The other answer by Átila shows how the correct proof goes.

Comment: THANK YOU, I knew I cheated somehow, thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 3):

What is the definition of $\sigma$-algebra? Given a non-empty set $\Omega$, we say that a collection $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets from $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra iff the following conditions hold:

- $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$,
- If $X\in\mathcal{F}$, then $X^{c}\in\mathcal{F}$,
- If $(A_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of sets such that $A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}$, then $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}$.

Based on such definition, we can prove the desired claim.

Firstly, notice that $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}_{1}\cap\mathcal{F}_{2}$: that is because $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}_{1}$ and $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}_{2}$.

Similarly, if $X\in\mathcal{F}_{1}\cap\mathcal{F}_{2}$, then $X^{c}\in\mathcal{F}_{1}\cap\mathcal{F}_{2}$. Indeed, if $X\in\mathcal{F}_{1}\cap\mathcal{F}_{2}$, then $X\in\mathcal{F}_{1}$ and $X\in\mathcal{F}_{2}$. Hence, by the definition of $\sigma$-algebra, one concludes that $X^{c}\in\mathcal{F}_{1}$ and $X^{c}\in\mathcal{F}_{2}$, that is to say, $X^{c}\in\mathcal{F}_{1}\cap\mathcal{F}_{2}$.

Finally, if $(A_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of subsets from $\Omega$ such that $A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}_{1}\cap\mathcal{F}_{2}$, then $A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}_{1}$ and $\mathcal{A}_{n}\in\mathcal{F}_{2}$. Therefore, due to the definition of $\sigma$-algebra, one concludes that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}_{1}$ and $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}_{2}$, whence it results that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}_{1}\cap\mathcal{F}_{2}$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

**Additional comments**

Such property allows us to define the $\sigma$-algebra generated by an arbitrary family of subsets $\mathcal{E}$ from $\Omega$ as the (unique) collection of sets $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ satisfying the next properties:

- the set $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,
- the set $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ contains $\mathcal{E}$,
- if there is another $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ over $\Omega$ such that $\mathcal{G}\supseteq \mathcal{E}$, then $\mathcal{G}\supseteq\sigma(\mathcal{E})$.

Comment: thank you for the proof and especially your additional comments, this helps me a lot!!

Comment: @Kam You are welcome! I am glad I could help you.